# ionic2 - How to get PlayerId after user subscribes in OneSingal

Tags: typescript, push-notification, ionic2, onesignal

I am developing an app using ionic2 and I want to retrieve the player id so I can store in my DB so my question is how to can I retrieve the OneSignal users' unique player after a user subscribes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have already installed and configured `OneSignal` plugin. Following is the code to get `PlayerId`-

```
 this.oneSignal.getIds().then(ids => { 
    console.log(JSON.stringify(ids['userId']));   //PlayerId
 });
```

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what I want